# Which RVM and Ruby version do you recommend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ubuntu, rvm

Sorry for the novice question, I'm a .NET developer but I figured I'd give Rails development a shot.
I found a tutorial that recommended installing RVM and using ruby 1.9.2. So I installed as instructed following the indicated versions, but when it came to running bundler to install packages there seemed to be a version issue (conclusion after searching the error). I ended up manually installed the extra packages (only sqlite3 1.2.5 at the time) but then had further issues.

To cut to the chase, I got pretty fed up and decided to start looking for something more up to date and still ran into issues. So I figured I'd ask here.
Which versions of ruby, rails, bundler, sqlite do you find work best together?
For reference, I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 in VirtualBox.
Also, slightly off topic, but do you feel this kind of issue is common?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is very much unsuited for SE, its almost entirely opinion based and and potential answers will quickly be out of date. On SE we deal with answers - not recommendations.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the welcome. Sorry for the opinion based question, but I'm not really sure of any other large collection of programmers online where I can ask. Also, I'm having issues with various package versions and looking for what people find works well together. Surely that's not opinion based but drawing on experience, so leaning more towards fact? Although, I consent that there will naturally be an opinion element to all answers given.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend that you start with Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) book that is available for free on-line. The book provides a comprehensive introduction to the Ruby on Rails eco-system, and has been kept up-to-date with the improvements, and uses very recent versions of `ruby` and `rails`.

The book recommends setting up a virtual development environment using [cloud9](https://c9.io) for the beginners, which takes out the dev environment setup complexity from the learning process.

Comment: Yes, a book that teaches Bootstrap, AJAX, jQuery, SASS, TDD, Git, RSpec. Sorry, I forgot, the book also teaches Rails. I'd never ever recommend a beginner this book. Remember: First impression is last impression, and Rails doesn't deserve this ikind of impression.

Comment: I see your point but respectfully disagree @Arslan.  I (along with thousands of others) started with this tutorial and never regretted it.  I wound up buying Hartl's eBook and use it most every day as a reference for common Rails patterns.  It is a bit of work to get through the tutorial, but you gain a solid foundation in Rails and related technologies as a result.  Plus it is just wrong to hate on this great tutorial on [Tau Day](http://tauday.com/)!

Comment: Where I said I hate this book. Believe me I love this book, but I don't love this as a first book to a novice. I keep on reading this book time and again like you do. But for a beginner, there are other excellent resources to get the novice up and running like Codeschool's Rails for Zombies course, Lynda.com's Rails course by Kevin Skoglund. I want a beginner to learn Rails when he wants to learn Rails. And when he is done, no doubt Hartl's book is best to move one.

Comment: Funnily enough, I'm actually using Hartl's tutorial and the suggested versions are what's giving me issues. Also, I'm not a complete beginner, I've been programming professionally for 4 years so I don't have much issue with steep learning curves and can happily skip various things like SASS, jquery etc as I'm already quite familiar and comfortable with them. Thank you for the input though, it's very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.2 and ruby 2.1.5 go great.  They have complete pre-installed packages for linux/OSS/Windows at installrails.com.  As for the version of RVM, I use RBENV which is a more lightweight type of RVM.  Follow this link to get setup with everything:

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you want to be able to use multiple versions of both Ruby and Rails. Here is a pretty good overview on how to get started in Ruby, and also with Rails:

http://hathaway.cc/post/69203784459/how-to-setup-mac-os-x-for-ruby-and-rails.

It's for Mac, but should be easily translatable to linux.

It uses rbenv instead of rvm, which is probably a matter of preference. Don't install POW though unless you specifically want to use it over the default server (it doesn't work well with Apache).

In terms of which version to use, anything 1.9 and up should be ok? Though I'm not sure what the differences are...

Comment: Probably another silly question, but why would I need to run various versions? Surely the most up to date should be sufficient? (Provided all packages used are compatible)

Comment: If you have multiple projects over time you may have to maintain multiple versions of Rails and the gems for different projects (which may require different versions of Ruby). 'Gem' refers to a 3rd party Ruby library - for example, 'Ruby on Rails' is just a bunch of Ruby gems.

Comment: And as you said, if packages (gems) that you have been using suddenly become not-compatible with a Ruby upgrade, it's useful to be able to develop in a previous version